# UrlRewriter.net Expression Examples

Tags: urlrewriter.net

I need some web.config examples for each expression types below :

`$number`

The last substring matched by group number number.

`$<name>`

The last substring matched by group named name matched by *(?< name > )*.

`${property}`

The value of the property when the expression is evaluated.

`${transform(value)}`

The result of calling the transform on the specified value.

`${map:value}`

The result of mapping the specified value using the map. Replaced with empty string if no mapping exists.

`${map:value|default}`

The result of mapping the specified value using the map. Replaced with the default if no mapping exists.

**Sample:**

```
<rewriter>
    <if url="/tags/(.+)" rewrite="/tagcloud.aspx?tag=$1" />
    <!-- same thing as <rewrite url="/tags/(.+)" to="/tagcloud.aspx?tag=$1" /> -->
</rewriter>
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found/guessed. Not tested.

$number : http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/using

```
<rewrite url="^(.*)/(\?.+)?$" to="$1/default.aspx$2?" />

$1 matches (.*)
$2 matches (\?.+)
```

$< name > : this one I'm not so sure on the regex, couldn't find anything in documentation

```
<rewrite url="^(?<group1>(.*))/(\?.+)?$" to="$<group1>/default.aspx$2?" />

$<group1> matches
```

${property} : http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/actions/set-property

```
<set property="branch" value="$3" />
<rewrite to="/showbranch.aspx?branch=${branch}" />
```

${transform(value)} : http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/transforms

```
<set property="transform-name" value="lower" />
<set property="value-to-transform" value="THIS WAS UPPER CASE" />

<redirect to="/WebForm1.aspx?q=${encode(${${transform-name}(${value-to-transform})})}" />

results in "/WebForm1.aspx?q=this+was+upper+case"
```

${map:value} : http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/transforms/static

```
<mapping name="areas">
    <map from="sydney" to="1" />
    <map from="melbourne" to="2" />
    <map from="brisbane" to="3" />
</mapping>

<rewrite to="/area.aspx?area=${areas:$3}" />

results in "/area.aspx?area=brisbane"
```

${map:value|default}

```
<mapping name="areas">
    <map from="sydney" to="1" />
    <map from="melbourne" to="2" />
    <map from="brisbane" to="3" />
</mapping>

<rewrite to="/area.aspx?area=${areas:$4|perth}" />

results in "/area.aspx?area=perth"
```